# What's the logic behind the noop functions in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, no-op

while browsing Wordpress core I came across a file called `noop.php` that hosts a bunch of empty functions.

```
 /* Noop functions for load-scripts.php and load-styles.php */

/**
 * @ignore
 */
function home_url() {}

/**
 * @ignore
 */
function includes_url() {}
...
```

what's the logic behind these functions?
why does the admin section of Wordpress need them?.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the explanation on [trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.1/src/wp-admin/includes/noop.php).

> Create a new file, `wp-admin/includes/noop.php`, which loads all of the noop functions for `load-script|styles.php` and is only loaded by those files. DRYs in the process.

[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is for: Don't repeat yourself.

It provides methods which are implemented elsewhere and should not be removed.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I came across that on "Wordpress Exchange" 
but I was hoping for a bit more explanation, or maybe an example like: 

If this method wasn't available to this file/script this "bad thing" will happen, so this is why we used an empty implementation of it.. 

you know like a tiny walkthrough

Comment: Got your point. I'll do some research, may be I can find sth. out.